# How to extract predicted values from stan_lmer()

Tags: stan, rstan

I fitted a stan_lmer model and tried to extract predicted (predict() function) but R suggested me to use posterior_predict() but cannot at this point plot the predicted vs observed plot, as I have a huge object that differ in lenght from the observed values

How can I do this? I need only one value for each row.

```
res = data.frame(Observed = train_inc$pulse,
                 Predicted = posterior_predict(fit))

Error in data.frame(Observed = train_inc$pulse, Predicted = posterior_predict(fit)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 33232, 4000
```

This is what I get so far

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`posterior_predict` gives you a matrix which is `ndraws` by `nobservations`.  Taking the mean of the columns will give you the expected prediction.

```
library(rstanarm)
library(lme4)

fit = stan_lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days+1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)

ppred = posterior_predict(fit)

sleepstudy$pred = colMeans(ppred)

plot(sleepstudy$Reaction, sleepstudy$pred - sleepstudy$Reaction)
```

I'm surprised `rstanarm` recomends posterior predict.  I would have thought using `posterior_linpred` would have made more sense.